# Python - Deleting the last few characters of specific files in a directory

Tags: python, rename

I'm trying to delete the last several characters of multiple files in a specific directory using the `rename` function. The code I have written using suggestions on this site looks like it should work, but it returns the error message:

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'test1.txt' -> 'test'

And here is my code:

```
import os

list = os.listdir("C:\\Users\\Jonathan\\Desktop")

for file in list:
    if file.startswith("test"):
        os.rename(file, file[0:4])
```

My code shows that for all files beginning with the word "test", delete all characters after it. As I said, to me it looks like it should work, but I am new at Python, and I don't even understand what the error message means.

Comment: You can use pyrenamer!

Comment: Note that this can leave you with multiple files named "test"; is that really what's needed?

Answer (score 1):

As you didn't specify the complete path to your file, it is likely that your program was saving the in your root directory. Also, you should not use `list` or `file` as variable names since they shadow two of Python's types.

```
import os

files_path = "C:\\Users\\Jonathan\\Desktop\\"

lst = os.listdir(files_path)

for file_name in lst:
    if file_name.startswith("test"):
        os.rename(files_path + file_name, files_path + file_name[:-4])
```

Comment: I think that the OP wants rename `test1.txt` to `test`. And this will rename `test1.txt` to `test1`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you actually in the folder where you're renaming? If not, the problem is likely that you're looking in the local folder (where you launched the program). Prepend that path to each file name:

```
import os

cwd = "C:\\Users\\Jonathan\\Desktop"
list = os.listdir(cwd)

for file in list:
    if file.startswith("test"):
        os.rename(cwd+file, cwd+"test")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import os

list = os.listdir("C:\\Users\\Jonathan\\Desktop\\")

for file in list:
    if file[:4] == "test":
        os.renames(list+file, list+file[:4])
```

And by the way, if you need find the files and rename them recursively(That means will find all directories in that directory). You can use `os.walk()` like this:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("C:\\Users\\Jonathan\\Desktop\\"):                                
    for name in files:
        if name[:4] == "test":
            os.renames(os.path.join(root, name), os.path.join(root, name)[:4])
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `os.rename()` with existing paths. if your working directory is not the directory containing the file your script will fail. this should work independently of your working directory:

```
files_path = "C:\\Users\\Jonathan\\Desktop\\"
lst = os.listdir(files_path)

for fle in lst:
    if fle.startswith("test"):
        os.rename(os.path.join(files_path, fle), 
                  os.path.join(files_path, fle[:4]) )
```

and avoid using `list` as a varaible name.

Comment: I think that the OP wants rename `test1.txt` to `test`.